# How do I pass variables between java classes?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a value of the two variables "getName" and "getImage" between those classes.

```
public class FruitsFragment extends Fragment {

    public FruitsFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);
        // Create a test list of vegs
        final ArrayList<Veg> vegs = new ArrayList<Veg>();
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));
        vegs.add(new Veg("FELFEL", R.drawable.splash));

        // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
        // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
        VegAdapter adapter = new VegAdapter(getActivity(), vegs);

        // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
        // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
        // word_list.xml layout file.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link VegAdapter} created above, so that the
        // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Get the {@link Word} object at the given position the user clicked on
                Veg veg = vegs.get(position);
                FelfelActivity fel = new FelfelActivity();
                fel.setImage(veg.getImage());
                fel.setDes(veg.getName());
                Intent intent = new Intent(FruitsFragment.this.getActivity(), FelfelActivity.class);
                FruitsFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class FelfelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int ID;
    String NAME;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Change to numbers
        setContentView(R.layout.felfel);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageF);
        imageView.setImageResource(ID);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.des);
        textView.setText(NAME);
    }

    public void setImage(int id){
        ID = id;
    }

    public void setDes(String name){
        NAME = name;
    }
}
```

and it doesn't seem to work, as when I run the app on my phone and tap on any element in the list it directs me to the correct activity but with no image or name, just a blank background.

I'd like to know if there's a way I can pass the value of "getImage" and set it to the ImageView called "imageF", and to set the value of "getName" to the TextView called "des".

Comment: Have you tried doing some research? I think we probably have 10 questions per week with exactly the same title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the details to the other activity in the intent you're using to start the activity:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(FruitsFragment.this.getActivity(), FelfelActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", name);
        intent.putExtra("image", image);
        FruitsFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next activity

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
```

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) for Intents has more information (look at the section titled "Extras").